# Systems of equations with numerical analysis

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, numerical-methods, mathematical-physics

If the differential equations

$$
y'' + 0.5yy'z = \sin(x)
$$

$$
y' - z'' + zy = \cos(y), \quad 0 \leq x \leq 6
$$

are rewritten as a system of (n) first-order differential equations, then (n).

I answered 6 because I thought we need to know have for y, y', y'', z, z', z''. But the actual answer is 4. I would appreciate it if someone could explain this for me!

Comment: The ode system involves two functions: $y$ and $z$ and both have the second as the maximum derivative so we need $2+2$ first order odes to find the canonical representation.

Comment: Yeah you are right, it makes sense!

Answer (score 1):

Explicitly, those equations are equivalent to the following system of first order ODEs:
$$
\begin{cases}
y'=p, \\
p'+0.5ypz=\sin(x), \\
z'=q, \\
p-q'+zy = \cos(y).
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: What about the equation for y and z? How do we solve them?

Comment: Since they are nonlinear, you probably need numerical methods to solve them.